# Unity3D 5: почему трясётся камера

Tags: unity3d

Прикрепляю скрипт к камере, казалось бы с начала всё хорошо, но когда камера сталкивается с другим коллайдером она начинает трястись даже когда отошла от того коллайдера и не сталкивается. (К камере я прикрепил `Rigidbody` и отключаю для неё гравитацию)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FlyingCamera : MonoBehaviour {

private Vector3 CameraDirection, CameraRotation;
    private Rigidbody CameraRigidbody;
    private float MouseX, MouseY;
    public float MinY = -80, MaxY = 90, Speed = 2;

    void Start () {
        CameraRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }

    void Update () {
        Mouse ();
        MouseRotation ();
        Movement ();
    }

    void Movement() {
        CameraRigidbody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        if (Input.GetKey (KeyCode.W))
            CameraRigidbody.AddRelativeForce (Vector3.forward * 10);
    }

    void MouseRotation () {
        float RotateX = MouseX, RotateY = MouseY;
        if (MouseY < MinY)
            RotateY = MinY;
        if (MouseY > MaxY)
            RotateY = MaxY;
        CameraRigidbody.MoveRotation(Quaternion.Euler(-RotateY, -RotateX, 0));
    }

    void Mouse () {
        MouseX = (Input.mousePosition.x * Speed) / ((float)Screen.width - 0.5f);
        MouseY = (Input.mousePosition.y * Speed) / ((float)Screen.height - 0.5f);
    }
}
```

Comment: А зачем тебе rigidbody?

Comment: А как можно по-другому?

Comment: +1, хз зачем на камере rigidbody